# Android: How to detect when Audio stops playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiorecord

I am having a problem with MediaPlayer class' setOnCompletionListener Method. in my project I have a button, which text is Play, and when I press on it, player starts playing and it's text is changed to Pause. I want to change button's text to Play again once the track has finished playing. I used this code, which doesn't work for me.

```
//in onCreate() method:

player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[0]);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                trackBtn.setText("Play");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I have it, if you have any more question please let me know:

```
  player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  IntroClip.execute(player);
}
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
  trackBtn.setText("Play");
}
```

Comment: I did as you, expect IntroClip part, but still doesn't work for me :/

Comment: please tell me your error message? or no exception? and did you try debug?

Comment: I put the Break point on onCompletion() method, but my application didn't reach it at all.

Comment: it's strange... I have just create example and it works with me. Please download and check it out. I am using API 15 Android 4.0.3. and you?

Comment: please download example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4E1qxhiuLQ6TUtQRXA2Vk5iVUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, min Api 15. Will look your example now.

Comment: I have found my mistake. Thanks a lot for your efforts, your code gave me the clue ;)

Comment: you are welcome, if you don't mind please make my response is your answer. Thank you